# Download Folder including Subfolder via wget from Dropbox link to Unix Server

Tags: unix, download, directory, dropbox, wget

I have a dropbox link like https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w4366ttcz6/AAB4kSz3adZ which opens the ususal dropbox site with folders and files. 
Is there any chance to download the complete content (tar or directly as sync) to a unix machine using wget? 
I have seen some posts here where single files were downloaded but could not find any answer to this. There is an api from Dropbox but that does not work on my server due to the 64 bit issue on my server and http://www.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons/dropbox-gallery-download#BASH_Version does also not work for me.... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 31):

This help article documents some parameters you can use to get different behaviors from Dropbox shared links:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

For example, using this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/igoku2mqsjqsmx1/AAAeF57DR2ou_nZGC4JPoQKfa

We can use the `dl` parameter to get a direct download. Using curl, we can download it as such:

```
curl -L https://www.dropbox.com/sh/igoku2mqsjqsmx1/AAAeF57DR2ou_nZGC4JPoQKfa?dl=1 > download.zip
```

(The -L is necessary in order to follow redirects.)

Or, with wget, something like:

```
wget --max-redirect=20 -O download.zip https://www.dropbox.com/sh/igoku2mqsjqsmx1/AAAeF57DR2ou_nZGC4JPoQKfa
```

Comment: perfect for me. I'd recommend using `curl -L -O url` instead of `> download.zip`

Comment: with the curl version make sure you've got ?dl=1 at the end of the link, when copying from dropbox it'll default to ?dl=0

Comment: Note that this might not work with files larger than 2GB!

Comment: This curl -L solution is the first solution of many I've looked at that has worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

You can use --content-disposition with wget too.

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/sh/igoku2mqsjqsmx1/AAAeF57DR2ou_nZGC4JPoQKfa --content-disposition
```

It will auto-detect the folder name as the zip filename.

Comment: this way is awesome !!

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you're probably better off [creating an app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create) that you don't publish, which can either access all your files, or just a dedicated app folder (safer). Click the generate API token button about halfway down the app's settings page, and store it securely! You can then use the dedicated download or [zip download API call](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download_zip)s to get your files from anywhere like so:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download_zip \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $MY_DROPBOX_API_TOKEN" \
    --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path": "/path/to/directory"}' \
    > useful-name.zip
```

Adding your token as an environment variable makes it easier & safer to type/script these operations. If you're using BASH, and you have `ignorespace` in your `$HISTCONTROL` you can just type + paste your key *with a leading space* so it's not saved in your history. For frequent use, save it in a file with `0600` permissions that you can `source`, as you would an SSH key.

```
 export MY_DROPBOX_API_TOKEN='...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  as it is pretty wasy follow below steps

Firstly, get the dropbox share link. It will look like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad2arn440pu77si/test.txt

Then add a “?dl=1” to the end of that url and a “-O filename” so that you end up with something like this: wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad2arn440pu77si/test.txt?dl=1 -O test.txt

Now you can easily get files onto your linux.