# Puppeteer pass on access token to wget (from Dropbox link login)

Tags: google-chrome, curl, puppeteer, wget, access-token

Sometimes is hard to do just [simple stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821995/how-to-click-on-a-link-that-has-a-certain-content-in-puppeteer) with puppeteer. I was wondering if it is possible to use puppeteer to login to a dropbox link with password and then use someting like `wget` or `curl` to do the rest. I imagine that I would need to read and then pass on on some sort of access token after the login.

Would this be possible?

(yes, I know that using the dropbox API would perhaps be an easier and more correct solution)

Comment: If you know where or in which format the token is stored, local/session storage, cookie secure or normal, then may be you can use curl or wget and pass the token with it. But like you said dropbox api will be an easier way

Comment: No I don't.. Is there an easy way to figure it out?

Comment: I created an account and tried clearing local and session storage , and refreshed the page, I am still authorized so it should be one of the cookies. I don't think there is an easy way, look for larger values in secure cookies and try removing them and refresh the page, if you are authorized then that's not the right cookie.

Comment: @karthick thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. Do you know how to get/read the cookie in puppeteer?

Comment: to read normal cookies just call the cookies method in the page object page.cookies() , but that wont include http cookies. So you need to use  Chrome devtools protocol, search for CDP network cookies, you should get some resources

Comment: You can store the cookies and reuse them. Here is the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515357/6189678)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar how puppeteer stores cookies, but I am sure you can do that, see references below, and e.g. the [Puppeteer API docu on cookies](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-pagecookiesurls).

Here my 50 cents on `wget` and/or `cURL` with access control. In both cases it is possible to load cookies which provide you access to dropbox. Assume you have them stored in `myAccessCookies.txt`, you can reload them and use them e.g. with wget:

```
wget -qO- --load-cookies myAccessCookies.txt http://www.example.com/replaceWithDropboxLink
```

**Another hint:** To my knowledge, Dropbox allows to share direct, temporary links to files which do not require further authentication, see e.g. https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/set-link-permissions - if this is not a security threat, and you can influence your counter-party to use these, everything is easy.

#### References and further reading

- [Superuser: How to download dropbox files using wget](https://superuser.com/questions/470664/how-to-download-dropbox-files-using-wget-command)
- https://www.apharmony.com/software-sagacity/2014/10/using-wget-with-cookies/ on how to use wget with cookies
- [Download Folder including Subfolder via wget from Dropbox link to Unix Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624523/download-folder-including-subfolder-via-wget-from-dropbox-link-to-unix-server)
- [How to save cookies and load it in another puppeteer session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514877/how-to-save-cookies-and-load-it-in-another-puppeteer-session)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515357/6189678 - how to store and reuse cookies (suggestion by [V.Kostenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6189678/v-kostenko))

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, feel free to comment, I will revise my answer.